# folium.GeoJson Confusion and Lost

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I am fairly new at Python and am working on learning to perform geospatial analysis. I am running the latest version of Python 3.7 in a Juypter notebook through the newest Anaconda (I just updated everything yesterday - 18 Jan 18). I am running a MacBook Pro, I-7, 16gb ram.

I am attempting to establish a layer on a basemap. The layer is a json file of census blocks for the city of Tacoma, Washington, from the U.S. Census Bureau.

This is the code that I am using:

```
tacoma = folium.Map(location=[47.26, -122.46], zoom_start = 12)

folium.GeoJson(open('../data/Tacoma-Census-Blocks.geojson')).add_to(tacoma)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(tacoma)
tacoma
```

I am receiving this ValueError message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-72546a798788> in <module>()
      3                     zoom_start = 12)
      4 
----> 5 folium.GeoJson(open('../data/Tacoma-Census-Blocks.geojson')).add_to(tacoma)
      6
      7 folium.LayerControl().add_to(tacoma)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/features.py in __init__(self, data, style_function, name, overlay, control, smooth_factor, highlight_function, tooltip)
    372                 raise ValueError(msg)
    373         else:
--> 374             raise ValueError('Unhandled object {!r}.'.format(data))
    375 
    376         self.style_function = style_function or (lambda x: {})


ValueError: Unhandled object <_io.TextIOWrapper name='../data/Tacoma-Census-Blocks.geojson' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>.
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
folium.GeoJson(open('../data/Tacoma-Census-Blocks.geojson', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'),name="geojson").add_to(tacoma)
```

If it doesn't work, try moving the file to the same folder:

```
folium.GeoJson(open('tacoma.geojson', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'),name="geojson").add_to(tacoma)
```